# Dúvida de ordenação - Linguagem C

Tags: c, classificação, array

Estou ordenando um vetor simples, de forma crescente. O código funciona.

Porém a seguinte linha em que me deixou confuso:

```
if (matriz[i] < matriz[j])
```

Porque o sinal ali é de menor, e não de maior? Se eu quero trocar as posições, caso a posição `i` seja maior que a posição `j`, porque o sinal é contrário a isso?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

int main()
{
    int k = NULL, *matriz = NULL, aux=0;    

    printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%i", &k);

    matriz = (int *)malloc(k * sizeof(int));
    srand(time(0));

    printf("\n");
    printf("NAO ORDENADO: ");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {

        matriz[i] = rand() % 100;

        printf("Posicao %d: %d", i + 1, matriz[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (matriz[i] < matriz[j])
            {
                aux = matriz[i];
                matriz[i] = matriz[j];
                matriz[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("ORDENADO: ");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("Posicao %d: %d", i + 1, matriz[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Chama-lhe antes vector: uma matriz unidimencional é como ter um cão chamado gato :)

Answer (score 1):

Vamos supor o seguinte vetor: `[2,5,1,6]`. Vou fazer passo a passo como o seu código vai tratar esse vetor pra ver se fica mais claro.

```
> 2 < 2? Não
[2,5,1,6]
> 2 < 5? Sim
[5,2,1,6] Como o dois é menor, ele troca de lugar com o cinco.
> 5 < 1? Não
[5,2,1,6]
> 5 < 6? Sim
[6,2,1,5]
```

Lembre-se que nesse momento "acaba" o primeiro *loop* do `for` de fora, então vamos começar a compara o segundo item do vetor com os demais:

```
> 2 < 6? Sim
[2,6,1,5]
[2,6,1,5]
> 6 < 1? Não
[2,6,1,5]
> 6 < 5? Não
[2,6,1,5]

> 1 < 2? Sim
[1,6,2,5]
> 2 < 6? Sim
[1,2,6,5]
> 6 < 6? Não
[1,2,6,5]
> 6 < 5? Não
[1,2,6,5]

> 5 < 1? Não
[1,2,6,5]
> 5 < 2? Não
[1,2,6,5]
> 5 < 6? Sim
[1,2,5,6]
>6 < 6? Não
```

Espero que tenha dado para entender.

Answer (score 1):

Julgo que a sua confusão reside no facto de o algoritmo usado ser pouco intuitivo.

Para que a comparação seja como você diz o algoritmo deverá ser assim:

Cada elemento do array `for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)` é comparado com os seguintes `for (int j = i + 1; j < k; j++)`)

Como a ordenação é crescente, se o elemento é maior que o seguinte deverão ser trocados `if(matriz[i] > matriz[j])`
Onde `i` é a posição do elemento em questão e `j` é a posição do elemento que está numa posição seguinte.

O último elemento não necessita de ser verificado porque a verificação do antepenúltimo garante que ele seja o maior de todos.

No seu código deverá alterar os dois ciclos para:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < k; j++)
    {
        if (matriz[i] > matriz[j])
        {
            aux = matriz[i];
            matriz[i] = matriz[j];
            matriz[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Este algoritmo é mais rápido, já que são necessárias menos iterações para chegar ao resultado.
Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/QvSF4W)