# Como usar opções de compilação no Ideone?

Tags: c, ideone

Ontem ao responder a esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60354/2541) quis testá-la no Ideone, ao correr o código recebi este erro:

> prog.c: In function 'main':
>   prog.c:12:9: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
>            for (int i = 0; i < k-1; j++)
>            ^
>   prog.c:12:9: note: use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code

Compreendi que o problema estava na declaração do `i` dentro do `for` e que a solução seria usar uma dessas opções de compilação ou declarar a variável fora do `for`.

Como não encontrei onde usar as opções de compilação tive que usar a outra solução.

Fica então a pergunta:
É possível usar opções de compilação no Ideone?
Se sim, como?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma das linguagens que se pode escolher é C99 strict

[image: C99 strict no ideone]

Comment: hehe! Nunca me passaria pela cabeça procurar aí.

Comment: Nem eles sabem: http://ideone.com/vjh5Fv